# Yahoo Mail now pops up an "Add Requests" tab when I log in. How do I stop that from happening?

Tags: yahoo-mail

Just within the past day or two, whenever I log into Yahoo Mail and click on Inbox, it automatically opens and displays a new tab on top of my Inbox, called "Add Requests":

[image: Annoying new Yahoo Mail Add Requests tab]

It is extremely annoying. Does anyone know how to disable this new tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I was signed into Yahoo Messenger. After signing out of it, this tab no longer appears when I log into Yahoo Mail.

1. Look for "Top Contacts" on the lower, left side of your screen.
2. If it's a yellow lightning bolt, click on it to sign out.

[image]

I don't happen to use Yahoo Messenger any more, so it doesn't matter to me that I have signed myself out. It would be nice, though, if there were a setting to disable this tab.

Comment: Or click on the arrow next to you name (top-left corner) and select **Sign Out of Messenger**.

Comment: Also, instead of **Top Contacts** you might have **Online Contacts**.